# How can I count the number of lines of a file with common tools?

Tags: files, grep

I am redirecting `grep` results to a file, and then using `cat` to show its contents on the screen. I want to know how many lines of results I have in my results file and then add it to some counter.

What will be the best way? Any relevant flag to `grep` or `cat`?

Comment: and you can use awk for simple linebased stuff, too ...

Answer (score 205, accepted):

If you have already collected the `grep` output in a file, you could output a numbered list with:

```
cat -n myfile
```

If you only want the number of lines, simply do:

```
wc -l myfile
```

There is absolutely no reason to do:

```
cat myfile | wc -l
```

...as this needlessly does I/O (the `cat`) that `wc` has to repeat.  Besides, you have two processes where one suffices.

If you want to `grep` to your terminal and print a count of the matches at the end, you can do:

```
grep whatever myfile | tee /dev/tty | wc -l
```

---

Note: `/dev/tty` is the controlling terminal. From the [`tty(4)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/4/tty):

> The file `/dev/tty` is a character file with major number 5 and minor number 0, usually of mode 0666 and `owner.group` `root.tty`. It is a synonym for the controlling terminal of a process, if any.
>
> In addition to the [`ioctl(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl) requests supported by the device that tty refers to, the [`ioctl(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl) request `TIOCNOTTY` is supported.

Comment: Note that `wc -l filename` will output the filename in addition to the number of lines. If you only want the number, use this form `wc -l < filename` -- since wc is now reading from stdin, there is no filename to print.

Comment: How to save the result of `wc -l < filename` into a variable to use later?

Comment: @Sigur : LINES=$(wc -l filename); echo ${LINES}

Comment: @Sigur : I should note that this is POSIX syntax in lieu of the archaic back-ticks often seen; viz. LINES=`wc -l filename`.  Modern shells that are POSIX compliant support the preferred $(...) It's much easier to read, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude... Using your answer 4th time. :)

i keep forgetting this and ur answer helps me the most

Comment: Is there a way (perhaps using tee?) that you can both save the number of lines and have the prints still come out?

Comment: @Chris, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72819/count-number-of-lines-of-output-from-previous-program

Comment: +1 for teaching me the `tee` thing. Brilliant.

Answer (score 88):

The `-c` flag will do the job. For example:

```
 grep -c ^ filename
```

will count the lines returned by `grep`.

Documented in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

> -c, --count
>       Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file

Comment: I think that `^` is confusing. Is that the string you are trying to match or something else?

Comment: `^` is not a string you are matching but the position of a possibly following string. If the string is left out it matches only the position. Which in this case, is the start of a line. So effectively, you are telling `grep` to count the lines.

Comment: `grep -c '' filename` will do the trick too.

Comment: Piping git log command output to `wc -l` returned the wrong number of lines (and thus of commits), but `grep -c ^` (or `grep -c $`) returned the correct number. Thanks

Comment: The `^` is an anchor, meaning the start of _any_ line. The corresponding `$` anchors to the _end_ of the line. https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Anchoring.html - Extremely useful when you need to be precise.

Answer (score 22):

Use

```
your_command | wc -l
```

From the manual:

```
NAME
       wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file

...

       -l, --lines
          print the newline counts
```

Answer (score 5):

Using AWK to count the lines in a file

```
awk 'END {print NR}' filename
```

Comment: This is better, `wc -l ` gives wrong count sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use wc -l to get line count.

Example:

```
$ cat foobar.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: This is the common shell mistake **Redundant cat**. The effect of this is to create a pipe, executing `cat file` with its output redirected to the pipe and `wc -l` with its input redirected from the pipe. But you can eliminate the entire invocation of "cat" by just redirecting wc's input to come from the file rather than the pipe. Just do `wc -l foobar.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use wc: it doesn't count the last line if it's not terminated by the end of line symbol (at least on mac).
Use this instead:

```
nbLines=$(cat -n file.txt | tail -n 1 | cut -f1 | xargs)
```