# Count number of lines of output from previous program

Tags: bash, shell, debian, command-line

I'm trying to count the number of lines of output a certain program produces. The problem is, the program takes a long time to run, and I want to display the output to the user. **Is there a way to count the number of lines the last command outputted?**

I could do `program | wc -l` but that wouldn't show the output to the user. So as far as I know, I have to do `program; program | wc -l` - but the program takes at least a minute to run, so I don't want to have to do it more than once just to show a line count at the bottom.

**EDIT:**

- **Is there a way of showing the output as it happens (line by line) and then returning a count at the end?**

Comment: How about: have the program keep track of its own output and just read that value from the variable (e.g. `STDOUT_WRITE_COUNT`), or log it to a file/API, at the end of the program. WDYT?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use `tee` to split the output stream sending one copy to `wc` and the other copy to STDOUT like normal.

```
program | tee >(wc -l)
```

The `>(cmd)` is bash syntax which means run `cmd` and replace the `>(cmd)` bit with the path to (a named pipe connected to) that program's STDIN.

Comment: `>(cmd)` is `ksh` syntax also recognised by `zsh` and `bash` and is only using _named pipes_ on systems that don't have `/dev/fd/n`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Yes, most shells support it, but it's not in POSIX, so it can't be relied upon to be everywhere.

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing out that process substitution was not a `bash` invention as the wording in your answer could let one believe.

Comment: @Patrick Is this more efficient than the answer below (using awk or sed)?

Comment: @TheLibbster Depends how you define efficient. This method does involve spawning 2 additional processes, where as `sed` and `awk` are just one. But `tee` and `wc` are both extremely small (much smaller than `sed` and `awk`).

Comment: @Patrick I meant efficient in terms of time it takes to complete.

Comment: @TheLibbster yes, according to some simple tests I just did, it's actually about twice as fast as both the `sed` and `awk` methods. (I `dd`d 100mb of `/dev/urandom` to a file and then ran that file through each method several times)

Answer (score 14):

One option is to use awk, which can do the counting and print to stdout.

```
program | awk '{ print } END { print NR }'
```

In `awk`, NR is the current line number. You can accomplish the same with perl:

```
program | perl -pe 'END {print "$.\n"}'
```

Or `sed`:

```
program | sed -n 'p;$='
```

Comment: Is there a way of showing the output as it happens (line by line) and then returning a count at the end?

Answer (score 10):

my favorite option:

```
program | grep "" -c
```

Comment: OP may have asked something else, but I came here looking for just getting a count of number of lines output and didn't care about showing the actual output, and this does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can clone stdout on stderr.

```
program | tee /dev/stderr | wc -l
```

That way, `program`'s stdout is piped to `tee` to be written to stderr, which is printed on the console. `tee` also writes the data piped to it to its stdout, which is piped to `wc`.

Answer (score 2):

This might be late. But I would just address your follow up question on how to catch the counted number in a variable.

This is what you want `YOUR_VAR=$(PROGRAM | tee /dev/stderr | wc -l)`.

We take advantage of `tee` generating two streams here and direct one to `/dev/stderr`, which would appear on you screen, and the other to `wc -l`, which would report the number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log | ( c=0; pl() { echo $c; c=0; }; trap pl SIGHUP; while read a; do (( c=c+1 )); done ) & ( trap 'kill $! ; exit' SIGINT; trap '' SIGHUP; while true; do kill -HUP $! ; sleep 1; done)
```