# Command output retention while counting lines

Tags: bash, grep, wc

I was reading [Count number of lines of output from previous program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72819/count-number-of-lines-of-output-from-previous-program?noredirect=1&lq=1&newreg=eb8241a63572495385250ff15273d63c)
and found it helpful. However, while

```
$ grep -i [pattern, file] | tee >(wc -l)
```

gives me a nice output of the grep lines *and* the number of matches, I want to ask if anyone knows how to save the number of matches to a variable in my script. I want to output it within a string with more readable formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
somevar=$(wc -l <(grep -i [pattern, file]) | awk '{print $1}')
```

Then later on

```
echo "This was the numbers reported: $somevar"
```

If you want to keep the output of `grep` in a file and still do the count:

```
$ wc -l <(grep -i [pattern, file] | tee somefile) | awk '{print $1}'

$ wc -l somefile
 364 somefile
```