# Automatically print number of lines of command line output

Tags: bash, shell, configuration, wc, fish

In my [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html), I am using [fish command timer](https://github.com/jichu4n/fish-command-timer) to automatically show the duration of each command after it has been executed. This is a neat feature, which I recommend.

Now I want something similar in addition to that: The number of lines, i.e. **after each command line I execute, the number of lines printed to stdout and/or stderr should be printed to stdout, too**.

*Example*:

Instead of

```
> cat /etc/mpd.conf
pid_file "/run/mpd/mpd.pid"
db_file "/var/lib/mpd/mpd.db"
state_file "/var/lib/mpd/mpdstate"
playlist_directory "/var/lib/mpd/playlists"
```

I want to see

```
> cat /etc/mpd.conf
pid_file "/run/mpd/mpd.pid"
db_file "/var/lib/mpd/mpd.db"
state_file "/var/lib/mpd/mpdstate"
playlist_directory "/var/lib/mpd/playlists"

[ 4 lines ]
```

*Some notes*:

- There are some manual solutions to print the number of output lines of a command [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72819/count-number-of-lines-of-output-from-previous-program), but I want this to be a permanent feature implemented in my fish config.
- I don't want to execute the command twice (for obvious reasons like the lack of idempotency etc.)
- A solution for bash (instead of fish) may point in the right direction.

The command timer works with a postexec event that is fired after executing a command line, but that does not exactly solve my problem, so I am in need of an approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `cat /etc/mpd.conf` with `cat /etc/mpd.conf | tee /proc/self/fd/2 | echo -e "\n[ $(wc -l) lines ]"`

If you can't use /proc/self/fd/ try splitting it into 2 commands or use the && operator for something like `cat /etc/mpd.conf && echo "Number of lines: $(cat /etc/mpd.conf | wc -l)"`

from [wc man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc):

> -l, --lines
>   print the newline counts

Comment: As I understand, the author of question wants solution, that will work for each command, not only the `cat`: " The number of lines, i.e. after each command line I execute, the number of lines printed to stdout and/or stderr should be printed to stdout, too."